# how to use a local filesystem in silverlight webbrowser control ?

Tags: html, silverlight, webbrowser-control

Hello everyone. I'm using Silverlight webbrowser control, and I'm having some problems with that. I'm trying to use a Html page in a webbrowser control in my silverlight project, and i want to load this page from the local filesystem. so I'm doing this:

```
string html = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/mehdi/Desktop/essai.html");
       wbNavigator.NavigateToString(html);
```

When doing this I have this exception: `Unauthorized file operation. Access to the path is denied`. Can anyone help me plz ?  thx .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of access the Silverlight app in question needs elevated permissions. Failing that you have two options:

- have the user browse to the file you want to use
- host the html on the server with your Silverlight

Comment: thw for your answer ! but how can my  silverlight application has this elevated permissions ?

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793(v=vs.95).aspx, for example. Note that it's not really an ideal solution, which is why I have suggested a couple of alternatives for you. Why do you want to use a local HTML file?

Comment: i have already try to check the checkbox "require elevated trust when ...." in out of browser settings ! but the exeption is still appearing .  so what is the problem ?

Comment: That checkbox does nothing if you're running in the browser. Have you followed the instructions from the link I gave you?

Comment: so this is my problem ! i want to use routing service of google map ! since google map api doesn't exist for silverlight im trying a workaround solution . i reference to a html page containing a javascript function that calculate a route between two points .  and i will invoke this one from my silverlight app .

Comment: How about this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring(v=vs.95).aspx use an iframe as in this link, but point the iframe to your local html file.

Comment: when trying this no thing apear in the lace of the iframe : wbNavigator.NavigateToString("<html><head></head><body>Silverlight Developer Site" +
    "<iframe src=\"file:///C:/Users/mehdi/Desktop/new.html\" WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=200>" +
        "</iframe></body></html>");

Comment: Alright, well looking at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.source(v=vs.95).aspx, it seems you cannot load a local resource that way. Could you try 'hosting' the html file you're trying to use on localhost, the referencing it that way?